# WordPress - Using featured post image with blog index.php template

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use the featured post feature of WordPress to display an image as a background on the blog template (not post or page).

This is the code I'm using in my template file:

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<style type="text/css">body { background: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>') }</style>
```

the style tag is being rendered on the page, but it's not getting the image source.

This same code (or, a very similar version of it), is working on my other templates - just not the blog page.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check what get_the_ID() returns on blog page.

Because most likely get_the_ID() will return nothing / non-post  (dont quote me on this ),  so there is no thumbnail to display.

When it is on blog page, what thumbnail do you want to display?

=== Added ===

If you want to display the very first  blog post's featured image as a background.

You will have to put your code **INSIDE LOOP**

However, because it is background image, you'd only want your code just once.

What you can do is put incremental variable so you know the 'index' of the loop

```
<?php $index = 0;
   if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if($index == 0) {
        *** your code comes here ***
     }     

    $index++;

   endwhile;

   endif; ?>
```

Comment: The featured post image thats attached to the blog page entry.

Comment: I'd assume, you want to display very first blog's thumbanil because it is a background of the template.   so you will have to try INSIDE LOOP so that it can grab the post id.     and put $index incremental so you can set up so that that background css only runs for the first blog post

Comment: This is what I've got so far, but there's something in here it doesn't like - I suspect some missing PHP opening/closing tags perhaps?`<?php $index = 0;
   if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if($index == 0) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
     <style type="text/css">body { background: url('echo $image[0];') }</style>

}     

    $index++;

   endif; ?>`

Comment: endwhile; before endif;    has been added.   See the updated code above

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there's something still stopping it

`<?php $index = 0;

   if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if($index == 0) {

  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
     <style type="text/css">body { background: url('echo $image[0]') }</style>

          }     

    $index++;

   endwhile;

   endif; ?>`

Comment: Can you be more specific?   have you checked error.log?      'not working', 'doesn't like it' doesn't give us any clue

Comment: Sorry, by 'not working' I mean that the template renders blank. I have no server access so I'm not sure about getting access to error logs.

Comment: In your wp-config.php, set WP_DEBUG to true  like   define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43464/discussion-between-joshuac-and-hsb1007)

Comment: No one in the chat =(